# X out and other button doesn't work in pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

so im trying to create a popup to input email and name for a subscription but the button to open the popup and close the popup don't work. The first subscription button should open the popup and there is an x that should close the popup could anyone try to debug it?

my code:

```
<div class="center">
            <button id="show-login">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Subscribe for more quizzes!</h2>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="password">Name</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
                    <label for="remember-me">Click for email notifications!</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <button>Subscribe</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js.:

```
document.querySelector("#show-login").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").classList.add("active");
});
document.querySelector(".popup .close-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").classList.remove("active");
});
```

Comment: Well I would need to see your css code. Your first event listener is triggered when the button is clicked, but I'd have to see how your css is written.

Comment: try to post css code its more helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

i am just add css like below

```js
document.querySelector("#show-login").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").classList.add("active");
});
document.querySelector(".popup .close-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".popup").classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.popup{
display:none;  
}

.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
            <button id="show-login">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Subscribe for more quizzes!</h2>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="password">Name</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
                    <label for="remember-me">Click for email notifications!</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <button>Subscribe</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you...!